# When I sign Eclipse change my Version Code

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, sign

I'm using Eclipse. I have a Android App in Google Play. My app Version Code : 3, Version Name 3.1 I chgane some code in my app then change version Code: 4 and Version Name 4.1. When I sign my app using old keystore file everything is ok but Eclipse changed Version Code 3 and Version Name 3.1 then I cant upload google play becouse Google play want to increase my app version code. I'm using  page under Use the Export Winzard link button.

Why Eclipse change my Version Code?

Thanks.

AndroidManifest.xml screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/btpiebok9/

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml screenshot`. Screenshot of text file?! C'mon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use project>clean... test run your project... then right click project>android tools>export signed apk....